# Single sign on for google api's using Scribe?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, gdata-api, google-api-java-client, scribe

Is there anyway to retrieve the Google Oauth refresh_token using Scribe?

I am building an app that requires several scopes mixed between java Gdata and Google api java client libraries -- and I am looking for a Single Sign On (SSO) when a user of my app signs in.  However because of the state of current Google Apps API's requiring Oauth 1 or Oauth 2 depending on which library / scope you need, I'm a bit stuck.

- Oauth 1 (java gdata e.g. analytics data export scope) - requires the
  access_token secret
- Oauth 2 (google api java client e.g. analytics calendar scope) -
  require a refresh token, which is not avail currently in a Scribe OAuth 1 call

Any tips / advice?  Anyone managing this with a single sign on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scribe has added support for Google OAuth API. I used scribe 1.2.2 and it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry scribe does not support (at the time of this writing) Google's OAuth 2.0 Apis.

It shouldn't be too hard to implement using [FacebookApi](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/FacebookApi.java) as a guide. Cheers!

Comment: Pablo, are you going to pull in Devashish's GoogleApi20 changes into the main scribe-java repository?

Comment: @Pablo, Now that Google has [officially deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref) their support for OAuth 1.0, would you please get OAuth 2.0 support for Google into Scribe?

Comment: hie I looked into the Scribe example for Google OAuth and the example atleast is only for OAuth1.0 ....has support for OAuth2.0 been released?